# How can I add a new enum value to a field in QuickFIX/J?

Tags: quickfixj

I want to add a custom enum value to a field in Quickfix.

For this purpose, I added new field (`NEW_VALUE`) to field (`DeleteReason`) on xml file. But this new enum field is not recognized on the app.

```
    <field number='285' name='DeleteReason' type='CHAR'>
        <value enum='0' description='CANCELLATION' />
        <value enum='1' description='ERROR' />
        <value enum='2' description='NEW_VALUE' />
    </field>
```

*Note: `<value enum='2' description='NEW_VALUE' />` is added by me.*

Do I need an operation for processing new xml file (we added new unrecognized field) or is it impossible adding new enum value?

Comment: If you want to use the new value in Java code you need to rebuild QFJ.